# CodeIgniter Uploadify doesn't upload files

Tags: codeigniter-2, uploadify

I don't get any error, nothing, but image isn't being uploaded, like controller isn't called at all, when I add in contruct function log_message I do not see anything in log file, not sure what is the problem. By the way I'm using this library(http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) to manage languages, so I have in url http://getit.mysite/en

Here is my controller function

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class FileUpload extends CI_Controller {

    public $view_data = array();
    private $upload_config;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function do_upload() {
        $this->load->library('upload');

        $image_upload_folder = base_url() . 'uploads/';

        if (!file_exists($image_upload_folder)) {
            mkdir($image_upload_folder, DIR_WRITE_MODE, true);
        }

        $this->upload_config = array(
            'upload_path' => $image_upload_folder,
            'allowed_types' => 'png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff',
            'max_size' => 2048,
            'remove_space' => TRUE,
            'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
        );

        $this->upload->initialize($this->upload_config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            echo json_encode($upload_error);
        } else {
            $file_info = $this->upload->data();
            echo json_encode($file_info);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

and js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var base_url = 'http://getit.mycom/';

    $('#upload-file').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#userfile').uploadify('upload', '*');
    });

    $('#userfile').uploadify({
        'auto': false,
        'swf': base_url + 'js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': base_url + 'js/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
        'uploader': base_url + 'fileupload/do_upload',
        'fileTypeExts': '*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png;*.tif',
        'fileTypeDesc': 'Image Files (.jpg,.bmp,.png,.tif)',
        'fileSizeLimit': '8MB',
        'fileObjName': 'userfile',
        'buttonText': 'Select Photo(s)',
        'multi': true,
        'removeCompleted': false
    });
});
```

and view file(add user) :

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
                                    <ul class="unstyled">
                                        <li>
                                            <?php echo form_upload('userfile', '', 'id="userfile"'); ?>
                                            <?php echo (isset($error)) ? $error : ''; ?>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <?php echo form_button(array('content' => 'Upload', 'id' => 'upload-file', 'class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')); ?>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors. I bet you're getting a 404 from the controller.

Comment: @Cryode I have double check that, before I have submit question here, I'm not getting anything in a console, network show me 302, that is found, but in the response, I do not get anything.

Comment: You're defining the `uploadify()` twice in your code -- is it because of that? Uploadify's site is down and I've never used it, so help will be difficult.

Comment: @Cryode Hi, no I'm not, I'm calling upload on click, will try with different plugin, I didn't know that uplaodify site is down, I saw that they have commercial plugin also, thought that will work.

Comment: Now their site is working, and I see what the click call is for.

302 header is a redirect, so that's likely your problem.

Comment: @Cryode hmm, sorry, I think that is related to language library. Will need to investigate it

Answer (score 0):

At the controller code, change `if (!$this->upload->do_upload())` to `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('Filedata'))`. Just try.